# Scala: Indexed Seq instead of List in for loop

Tags: scala

The following code shows a type mismatch error :

```
def f(arr:List[Int]): List[Int] = 
  for(num <- 0 to arr.length-1; if num % 2 == 1) yield arr(num)
```

It is says that it found an `IndexedSeq` instead of a `List`. The following works :

```
def f(arr:List[Int]): List[Int] = 
  for(num <- (0 to arr.length-1).toList; if num % 2 == 1) yield arr(num)
```

I have used `i <- a to b` in a for loop before but haven't seen this error before. Can someone please explain why the format `i <- a to b` cannot be used here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because `0 to arr.length-1` return type is: `IndexedSeq[Int]`, so when execute `for yield` it also will yield result with `IndexedSeq[Int]` type.

The correct function define:

```
 def f(arr:List[Int]):IndexedSeq[Int] = for( num <- 0 to arr.length-1 if num%2==1) yield arr(num)
```

And

```
for( num <- 0 to arr.length-1 if num%2==1) yield arr(num)
```

will translate to:

```
scala> def f(arr:List[Int]) = (0 to arr.length-1).filter(i => i%2==1).map(i => arr(i))
f: (arr: List[Int])scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]
```

So we can see the return type is decided by `0 to arr.length-1` type.

and `(0 to arr.length-1).toList` is changing the return `IndexedSeq[int]` type to `List[Int]` type, so `for yield` will generate result with type of `List[Int]`.

Comment: You can miss the semicolon out. `for( num <- 0 to arr.length-1  if num%2==1) yield arr(num) `

Comment: Removed, Thanks, @TheArchetypalPaul

Answer (score 3):

In Scala, for each iteration of your for loop, yield generates a value which will be remembered. **The type of the collection that is returned is the same type that you were iterating over**, so a List yields a List, a IndexedSeq yields a IndexedSeq, and so on.

The type of `(0 to arr.length-1)` is `scala.collection.immutable.Range`, it's Inherited from `scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]`. So, in the first case, the result is `IndexedSeq[Int]`, but the return type of function `f` is `List[Int]`, obviously it doesn't work. In the second case, a List yields a List, and the return type of `f` is `List[Int]`.

You can also write function `f` as follow:

```
def f(arr: List[Int]): IndexedSeq[Int] = for( a <- 1 to arr.length-1; if a % 2 == 1) yield arr(a)
```

Another example:

```
scala> for (i <- 1 to 5) yield i
res0: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> for (e <- Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) yield e
res1: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

In scala `for` is a [syntax sugar](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html), where:

```
for (i <- a to b) yield func(i)
```

translate to:

```
RichInt(a).to(b).map({ i => func(i) })
```

`RichInt.to` returns a `Range`

`Range.map` returns a `IndexedSeq`

Comment: Okay, but my question was, for( num <- 0 to arr.length-1 ; if num%2==1) yield arr(num), should work right ? .. but it doesn't ( on hackerrank atleast ) Why ?

Comment: it works, but its return type is `IndexedSeq` which doesn't match your function declaration.